# How to remove/unset specific array in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, multidimensional-array

How to remove/unset specific array in javascript? I tried to use splice but i get different result. I think I'm missing something here.

```
var arr = [12, 3, 150];
var min = 100;
var max = 200
for (var key2 in arr) {
    if (min > arr[key2] || arr[key2] >= max) {
        arr.splice(key2, 1);
    }
}
console.log(arr);
```

Current code output:    [ 3, 150 ]

Expected output: [150]

Comment: Use `filter` method and provide predicate in its callback

Comment: You should not change the array size inside a loop, unless you handle it. Try to debug this code and see what happens in the second iteration, for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) is way to solve your problem:

```js
var arr = [12, 3, 150];
var min = 100;
var max = 200


console.log(arr.filter(e => e > min && e < max))
```

Comment: Thanks didn't know that's how to use filter.